# Возможна ли в JavaFX привязка наблюдаемого свойства к какому-либо JavaFX-элементу?

Tags: java, javafx

В этом [уроке по JavaFX](https://code.makery.ch/ru/library/javafx-tutorial/part3/) предложено создать приложение - адресную книгу. Человека, занесённого в эту адресную книгу, можно удалить, предварительно выбрав его в списке, однако нужно как-то адаптировать приложение к случаю, когда пользователь нажал кнопку "удалить" предварительно никого не выбрав.

> Мы должны сообщать пользователю о том, что он, перед тем как нажимать
>   кнопку Delete, должен выбрать запись в таблице. (Ещё лучше совсем
>   деактивировать кнопку, чтобы у пользователя не было соблазна сделать
>   что-то не так).

Автор урока абсолютно прав насчёт дезактивации кнопки, но почему-то пошёл именно первым путём. Однако умение менять состояние элементов является необходимым при изучении UI-фреймворков.

Конечно, мы можем прицепить к обработчику события выбора адресата `personTable.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener()` разблокировщик кнопки, но хотелось бы использовать концепцию привязки свойств и данных, которая имеется не только в веб-приложениях, но и, например, Windows Presentation Foundation и Universal Windows Platform.

```xml
<ButtonBar>
  <buttons>
    <Button text="Add new…" />
    <Button text="Edit …" />
    <Button 
        onAction="#handleDeletePerson" 
        text="Delete" 
        <!-- Неверный синтаксис -->
        disabled="{{selectedIndex < 0}}"
    />
  </buttons>
</ButtonBar>
```

Разумеется, что `selectedIndex < 0` разумно вынести в какое-либо отдельное свойство:

```java
@FXML
private disableDeleteButtonFlag = selectedIndex < 0;
```

Возможно ли это в JavaFX?

Comment: Я как джавист не понял что Вы пытаетесь сделать)

Comment: @SerhiiDikobrazko, Благодарю Вас за то, что прочли мой вопрос. Скажу так: есть какое-то свойство класса; меняем  его значение на false - автоматически меняется статус кнопки на disabled. Меняем значение свойства на true - статус disabled исчезает. Мне нужно примерно это, только наличие статуса disabled у кнопки зависит не напрямую от булевского свойства класса, а от условия selectedIndex >= 0 (оно означает, что какой-то элемент из строк таблицы выбран).

Comment: Я понял. Их есть в javaFx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Лучше всего, все завязывать на свойствах. Их можно изменять, прослушивать события изменения, связывать

```java
// Свойство кнопки
// BooleanProperty buttonDisableProperеy = button.disableProperty();
BooleanProperty buttonDisableProperеy = new SimpleBooleanProperty(true);

// Наше свойство, где будет хранится условие для отключения кнопки
BooleanProperty myProperty = new SimpleBooleanProperty(false);
System.out.println(String.format("Button disabled:%s, myProp:%s", buttonDisableProperеy.get(), myProperty.get()));

// Связываем два свойства
buttonDisableProperеy.bindBidirectional(myProperty);

/* 
//в слушателе событий списка при выборе проверяем выбран ли хоть один элемент
//если не выбран ни один, то значение будет false, деактивироваь кнопку
else myProperty.setValue(selectedElemenеs ==0);
*/
myProperty.setValue(true);
System.out.println("myProperty has been changed");
System.out.println(String.format("Button disabled:%s, myProp:%s", buttonDisableProperеy.get(), myProperty.get()));
```

Comment: мне кажется   `myProperty.setValue(selectedElemenеs == 0)` в данном случае правильнее, чем конструкция if - else

Comment: @pavlofff нуууу, да)  "if(true) return true" Я как-то об этом не думал

Comment: Благодарю Вас за ответ!